# Accessing Pages in Section file from OneNote Interop

Tags: c#

I have a handful of OneNote `.one` files. I would like to extract their contents programatically. I'm getting stuck trying to access pages.

I'm calling:

```
app.OpenHierarchy(@"C:\test\TestSection.one", 
  System.String.Empty, out strXML, CreateFileType.cftNone);
```

in strXML is an ID.

Then I call:

```
app.GetHierarchy(strXML, HierarchyScope.hsPages, strXML2);
```

This returns an XML block with only `<one:Section.../>`. It has attributes that match the ID in strXML and the path to the physical .one file.

I have verified these .one files open in OneNote. I can see that this test.one has a bunch of pages. What am I doing wrong or missing here?

I'm using Office 2013 (v.15) and VS 2013 (I had to set Embed InteropTypes to False in the OneNote Interop v.15 reference to get things to build).

Answer (score 0):

Once you call app.GetHierarchy using the HiearchyScope.hsPages, you will now have all of the notebooks, sections, and pages that were stored in your TestSection.one file.  Here is an example if you wanted to traverse through the hieararchy of the notebooks, sections, and pages after you have called GetHierarchy.

```
var notebookName = "My Notebook";
var sectionName = "My Meetings";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(strXML2);
var ns = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
var myNotebook = xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Notebook").SingleOrDefault(n => n.Attribute("name").Value == notebookName);
if (myNotebook != null)
{
    var mySection = myNotebook.Descendants(ns + "Section").SingleOrDefault(s => s.Attribute("name").Value == sectionName);
    if (mySection != null)
    {
        var pages = mySection.Descendants(ns + "Page");

        // Now do something here with the pages!
        // ...
    }
}
```